# What world records have been broken by an athlete with a disability?

Tags: records

I wonder which world records have been broken by an athlete with a disability, put aside sports where non-disable athletes do not compete. For [example](http://www.guinnessworldrecords.com/news/2015/12/paralympic-armless-archer-matt-stutzman-hits-long-distance-target-to-score-worl-409657), the record *furthest accurate distance – men’s archery* was broken by an athlete with a disability.

Comment: Distance runner [Marla Runyan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marla_Runyan), who is legally blind (Stargardt's Disease, if I recall correctly - she has some vision but not much) represented the USA at the 2000 and 2004 Olympics and won numerous national championships. No world records, though.

Answer (score -1):

Apparently long distance runners are consistently beaten by their wheelchair counterparts. [This article on the topic](https://www.theguardian.com/sport/2016/sep/08/can-disabled-athletes-outcompete-able-bodied-athletes) reads

> ... in every distance race further than 400m, the world record times of wheelchair athletes are faster than their able-bodied counterparts.

It goes on to give full detail and information about the disparity between able-bodied long-distance runners and wheelchair ones.

Comment: I don't really think that's a fair comparison - cyclists are faster than runners as well. Change the method of locomotion to a far more efficient method and of course they're going to go faster.

Comment: Agreed - wheelchair racing and running are *de facto* different sports, although they share the same venues and many of the same rules.